# InputStream skip bytes

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, wireshark, bittorrent

I'm communicating with peers using TCP Sockets and I see that when I read the `inputStream` for the first incoming message, all goes well. Then when I read the `inputStream` for the second incoming message, the `inputStream` **skip** the first `n` bytes (`n` is a different positive number in each run).

How do I know that `inputStream` skip `n` bytes? Using Wireshark, I can see that the second message received well but Java TCP socket still ignore the first `n` bytes.

Moreover, Wireshark itself show me something strange - by looking at the first message in Wireshark, it contains at the end: the start of the second message. And by looking at the second message in Wireshark, the start of the message appears here also.

I can't understand what is going on.

Technical details + Wireshark photos:

1. The first message I receive is a 'Handshake' message.
2. The second message I receive is different each time but most of the time it's 'extended' message.
3. I checked in my code and I only read the same `InputStream` in 2 places: When I'm waiting for 'Handshake' and when I'm waiting for the rest of the messages which is not equal to 'Handshake' message.

The first message I receive:

```
 * Offset       Size            Name        value
 * 0            8-bit           byte        pstrLength
 * 1            pstrlen-bit     bytes       pstr
 * 1+pstrlen    64-bit          byte        reserved
 * 9+pstrlen    20-bit          String      torrentInfoHash
 * 29+pstrlen   20-bit          String      peerId
 * 49+pstrlen
public HandShake(InputStream dataInputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = new byte[1];
    dataInputStream.read(data);
    byte pstrLength = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).get();
    data = new byte[pstrLength + 48];// how much we need to read more.
    dataInputStream.read(data);

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1 + pstrLength + 48);
    byteBuffer.put(pstrLength);
    byteBuffer.put(data);
    HandShake handShake = HandShake.createObjectFromPacket(byteBuffer.array());
```

[image]

Details: `13` until `45` is the content of the first message - `Handshake`. `00` until `3a` is the first `n` bytes fo the second message which will appear also in here:

The second message I receive:

```
public static PeerMessage create(Peer from, Peer to, InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = new byte[4];
    boolean isPeerClosedConnection = (inputStream.read(data) == -1);
    if (isPeerClosedConnection)
        throw new IOException("the peer closed the socket:" + from.toString());
    int lengthOfTheRest = ByteBuffer.wrap(data).getInt(); // how much do we need to read more
    data = new byte[lengthOfTheRest];

    isPeerClosedConnection = (inputStream.read(data) == -1);
    if (isPeerClosedConnection)
        throw new IOException("the peer closed the socket:" + from.toString());

    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + lengthOfTheRest);;
    byteBuffer.putInt(lengthOfTheRest);
    byteBuffer.put(data);

    return create(from, to, byteBuffer.array()); // initialize message object from byte[]
}
```

[image]

Details: `00` until `3a` is the first `n` bytes of the second message.

When I read the `InputStream`, I get the following bytes: from `6d` to `65`.

**Why Wireshark shows the same data twice and why my `InputStream` skip the first `n` bytes of the second message?**

Comment: Could it be that the read of the "handshake" buffers up some additional bytes, and then your code discards that buffer and starts from scratch when reading the payload?

Comment: Not in this case. I calculate how much to read and I use every byte I read. Also, maybe it is good to mention that it happens only in 10% of the sockets. I think that If I can explain why Wireshark show me the same data twice, I will have more clues for this problem.

Comment: Yes in this case. You have a bug in your code, almost certainly the one suggested by @dasblinkenlight. `InputStream` doesn't behave like this. You can't just post questions positing bizarre behaviour of well-known APIs without providing the code that uses them so we can diagnose.

Comment: @EJP I added the code where I use `InputStream`. These are the only places I use it in all my project. As I said in my last comment -  I think that If I can explain why Wireshark show me the same data twice, I will have more clues for this problem.

Comment: How do you call the create and handshake methods, how many bufferedinputstream's do you make (it should be exactly 1 or less per connection)

Comment: @Ferrybig I create it one time and send it (without using it) to both the methods. After I get the first message, I wait for the second message by running `create` and sent the same `inputStream` to it. (If you still think it is relevant to see that code I will add it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> I calculate how much to read and I use every byte.

You coded:

```
data = new byte[pstrLength + 48];// how much we need to read more.
dataInputStream.read(data);
```

This code does not conform with your description. The second `read()` is not guaranteed to fill the buffer. See the Javadoc. Change it to `readFully()`.

NB There is another problem, in your `isPeerConnected` test. You are reading a byte of input and throwing it away. This will cause you to lose synchronization with the peer if it is still connected.

Comment: I use `InputStream` and not `DataInputStream` . I changed now to `DataInputStream` and I'm using `readFully`. I don't see any problem anymore :) Let me run some tests to make sure the behavior stays that way.

Comment: Everything is working great! You have a good eye, thanks so much!

Comment: You used an `InputStream` but you called the variable `dataInputStream`? Don't do that. It only causes confusion. One day you will confuse yourself.